# Is there a way to get the max of a JSON array in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7

For reasons I can't control, I need to parse a json column in MYSQL for all of the instances of a key and then get the max of those. Let's say the column name is json_data and the json looks like this:

```
    {
        list_of_stuff: {
            {
                value_i_want: 1
            },
            {
                value_i_want: 2
            },
            {
                value_i_want: 4
            },
            {
                value_i_want: 3
            }
        }
    }
```

Where I would need to get the maximum of the value_i_want tag, which in this case would be 4.

Right now I have the following code:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_data->"$.list_of_stuff", "$**.value_i_want") from table_name;
```

But it is returning JSON arrays, and when I try to get the maximum of those arrays, it is just returning the row with the longest json array, not the maximum value of each of those arrays.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**
My MYSQL version is 5.7.25

Answer (score 3):

your json is not valid as per json validator so i am considering below valid json :

```
{
  "list_of_stuff": [
    {
      "value_i_want": 1
    },
    {
      "value_i_want": 2
    },
    {
      "value_i_want": 4
    },
    {
      "value_i_want": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

this can be work with **mysql 5.7** :

**create mysql function for returning max value and then you can use this function with any select query.**
[see example](https://paiza.io/projects/DK_wXdMr90TP5dvZuURBLg?language=mysql)

```
create table Test(id integer, name json);
insert into Test(id, name) values(1, '{
  "list_of_stuff": [
    {
      "value_i_want": 1
    },
    {
      "value_i_want": 2
    },
    {
      "value_i_want": 4
    },
    {
      "value_i_want": 10
    }
  ]
}');

-- Your code here!

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION getMax(s JSON) RETURNS CHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE max INT;
    DECLARE temp INT;
    SET max = JSON_EXTRACT(s, '$[0]');
    WHILE i < JSON_LENGTH(s) DO
        SET temp = JSON_EXTRACT(s, CONCAT('$[',i,']'));
        IF max < temp THEN
            SET max = temp;
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN max;
    END
//
DELIMITER ;

SELECT getMax(JSON_EXTRACT(name->"$.list_of_stuff", "$**.value_i_want")) FROM Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL version 8.0  possible by creating temporary **json_table** and then find max().

[DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6cACJ3anDZZStHvgbkMqrF/0)
    create table Test(id integer, name json);

```
insert into Test(id, name) values(1, '{
  "list_of_stuff": [
    {
      "value_i_want": 1
    },
    {
      "value_i_want": 2
    },
    {
      "value_i_want": 4
    },
    {
      "value_i_want": 3
    }
  ]
}');

SELECT @json_var := cast(JSON_EXTRACT(name->"$.list_of_stuff", "$[*]") as char(200))  from Test;
SELECT max(tt.ac)
     FROM
      JSON_TABLE(
        @json_var,
       "$[*]"
        COLUMNS(
           rowid FOR ORDINALITY,
          ac int PATH "$.value_i_want" 

         )
  ) AS tt;
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without MYSQL 8? I am on 5.7.25